# Creating Model with Sub Model in one Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Item Model which includes common attributes and I have three different sub models FoodItem, ClothesItem and ElectronicItem.

If I'm passing the ItemType and the required fields for the sub model in a POST request, I would like to create both objects in one call without calling two serializers with the one to one relation. I found few questions with this issue, but it was complaining that the item_id is missing when creating the sub model.

code example:

```
class Item(models.Model):
        ITEMTYPE = (
            (1, 'Food'),
            (2, 'Clothes'),
            (3, 'Electronic')
        )
        itemType = models.IntegerField(choices=ITEMTYPE)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
        date_deleted = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
        price = models.IntegerField()

class FoodItem(models.Model):
        item = models.OneToOneField(Item, blank=True)
        foodType = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
        calories = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: kindly show your code in views.py and the error you got when you ran it

Comment: This is nested serializer. You need to override create method in nested serializer.http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the serializer you can flatten the data by explicitly defining the fields and using the `source` argument to point to the related model name: source='food_item.calories' for example.

As for the creation, you'll need to create the `Item` instance first and then the `FoodItem` by passing the serializer's validated_data `foodType`, `calories` *and* providing the previously created `Item` instance.